# Why is an EditText required for SoftInput to show in a DialogFragment?

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-dialogfragment

I have a custom class that extends a `DialogFragment`.  I came across some interesting behavior.  If an `EditText` is added dynamically, when focused the SoftInput keyboard doesn't show.

```
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    root = new LinearLayout(getActivity());
    root.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

    LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    Button button = new Button(getActivity());
    button.setLayoutParams(params);
    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            addEditText();
        }
    });

    root.addView(button);

    return new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
        .setView(root)
        .create();
}

private void addEditText() {
    EditText editText = new EditText(getActivity());    
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    editText.setLayoutParams(params);
    root.addView(editText);
}
```

If the `EditText` is added before the call to `setView` everything works fine.  It only happens if the `EditText` is added after.  **A simple workaround for this is to add an `EditText` to the root view and set its visibility to 'gone'.**  After this all other dynamically added `EditText`'s will work fine.

My question is: **Is this a bug in the Android system?**  Or is there some reason this is happening that I am overlooking.

*Note: The workaround works, but it took some time to find, and it just feels like a bug.*